# Using conditional rolling count with a group by in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataset -

```
Id Category 

1  Active  
1  Active   
1  Active   
1  End      
2  Paused  
2  Active   
2  Active
```

Expected output is a new column based on the counter which uses group by id, and resets the counter when category changes.

Expected output :-

```
Id Category Count

1  Active   0
1  Active   1
1  Active   2
1  End      0
2  Omitted  0
2  Active   0
2  Active   1
```

I have already used the following -

```
m = df['Category'] != df['Category'].shift(-1)
df['count'] = np.where(m, df.groupby(m.ne(m.shift(),'Id').cumsum()).cumcount()+1, 0)
```

but it fills with only 0

Also I have tried this -

```
mask = df['Id'] == df['Id'].shift(-1)
df['CatChange'] = df['Category'] != df['Category'].shift(-1)
count = df[mask].groupby('Id').cumcount()
df['CatChange_num'] = count
```

This just increments value without considering Category change.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['Id','Category']).cumcount()
```

And if you want your count to start from 1, you can do:

```
df['count2'] = df.groupby(['Id','Category']).cumcount() + 1
```

Which `print`:

```
   Id Category  count  count2
0   1   Active      0       1
1   1   Active      1       2
2   1   Active      2       3
3   1      End      0       1
4   2   Paused      0       1
5   2   Active      0       1
6   2   Active      1       2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `groupby` two column and `cumcount`

```
df.groupby(['d','Category']).cumcount()
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
dtype: int64
```